# Linux send with MSG_DONTWAIT blocks?

Tags: linux, send, glibc, nonblocking

in my multithreaded linux server application, a thread gets stuck forever in `send` function, which I believe should be nonblocking. The code looks like this:

```cpp
while(size) {
    const ssize_t sent = send(unixSocketFD, data, size, MSG_NOSIGNAL | MSG_DONTWAIT);
    if(sent > 0) {
        size -= sent;
        data += sent;
    } else {
        if(-1 == sent) {
            if(EINTR == errno) {
                continue;
            }
            if(EWOULDBLOCK == errno || EAGAIN == errno) {
                return 0; // need to be called again later
            }
        }
        return -1; // indicate error ...
    }
}
```

... and the stacktrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7bca9ff in __libc_send (fd=5, buf=0x7fffedd25880, n=87643, flags=16448) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/send.c:26
#1  0x00000000004076cf in Output::sendBlock (this=0x7fffdc0a3190, unixSocketFD=5) at OutputBlock.cpp:24
...
```

I believe that the `send` should return immediately when flags contain `MSG_DONTWAIT`. What's wrong with my code/assumptions? Thanks you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, this was my mistake: the `send` was not blocking, instead it was enterered again and again even if it indicated that the socket is not ready to accept more data.